# html web page resizing

Tags: html, iframe, resize

i have some buttons and iframe in my html page.certain pages are loaded into the iframe according to the button clicked.I have set the width and height of iframe and all in pixels.I need to dynamically resize my page according to the browser window.Please help me

Comment: Your question is very broad. You need to provide either specific code (recommend using http://jsfiddle.net/) or a more specific question discussing certain elements and how they adapt, then we can help.

Comment: It seems the steps that you might want to take are: Using an onclick js event handler with that button of yours, resize the page to whatever size you would like it to be. You question is rather vague

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the dimensions dynamically based on device screen using Media Queries in CSS. By using media queries you can specify screen size range and follow it by the desired CSS specifications (e.g Iframe Width and Height)

It is small topic , please have a look to this [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) at W3Schools. Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but try using in jquery `h=$(window).height()` to get the current height then `$('body').height=h` on the `.resize` event for `body`. I'm not even sure if it's valid code but this is the idea

Answer (score 0):

you can use twitter bootstrap and media queries to solve this.. also try % rather than pixels.
[twitter bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)